# Difference between forced and not forced lookups in twig/Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

in the getting started tour of Symfony2 i came across this:

```
    {# array('user' => array('name' => 'Fabien')) #}
{{ user.name }}

{# force array lookup #}
{{ user['name'] }}

{# array('user' => new User('Fabien')) #}
{{ user.name }}
{{ user.getName }}

{# force method name lookup #}
{{ user.name() }}
{{ user.getName() }}
```

Can someone explain me the difference?

Comment: Did I get something wrong, or did you maybe mean twig, instead of yaml? Don't see, where this is related to yaml :X

Comment: Oops, sry, of course i meant twig. Don't know how i came up with yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In twig when you just use `foo.bar`, `foo` may be an array (in this case twig expects a key `bar`), or an object, whereas it expects either a accessible property `bar`, a methods `getBar()`, and I guess something I forgot. However, the point is, that twig tries to resolve the kind of access itself and you can throw in, whatever you like (beside that it must obviously in a form of structured data). If you use a specific access method, you take the ability to guess from twig: When you call `foo.bar()` it's obviously a method. (Must say, that I never heard of "forced lookup" :X)

Comment: aha. That makes sense, thanks. Thought there was more behind it. :)

Comment: Nope, it's just easier to read `{{ user.name }} in {{ user.address }}` instead of `{{ user.getName() }} in {{ user.getAdress() }}`, because it's more natural. And thats whats templating about: Make easy overviewable ... yeah, templates ^^ (Arrays becomes more and more uncommon for structured data)